# minification Of JS And CSS In Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with Asp.Net MVC And i Use Jquery and Requir JS To Load JavaScript Files 
Like This:

```
   require(['backboneModal', 'ModalDialog', 'Java Script File Name'], function (backboneModal, ModalDialog, OpenSavedFilterModal) {

        OpenSavedFilterModal.getModal(portFolioNameSpace); 
    });
```

now i want to minification   Java Script Files:
 i use Squishit For Java Script Files Which load in Views like this:

```
   @Html.Raw(SquishIt.Framework.Bundle.JavaScript()
            .Add("~/Scripts/example.js")
            .ForceRelease()
    .Render("~/scripts/combined_#.js")
```

)
and it works .but files which loaded with Required don't change

Comment: Use Grunt : http://blog.simontimms.com/2013/12/30/grunt-your-asp-net-builds/

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use bundles that come with the nuget package Microsoft Web Optimization. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/

This way you can still reference the files from js.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Haven't used squish it or requir though so I might be wrong

Comment: Thank u for reply, but Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization is not working with requirejs